# Created file for ringtone doesn't have any sound

Tags: android, android-file, ringtone

I made my app to get file from Raw folder and set that file as `Ringtone`.
But there is a problem, the file is created and set as ringtone: http://prntscr.com/2so80e
But file does not have any sound, and idk why I am guessing by default my device is playing another ringtone.
Here is my code:

```
case 64:        
    String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"+R.raw.fusrodah;
    File k= new File(path);
    Log.i("OUTPUT", path);

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k .getPath());
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "Fusrodah File");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/ogg");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "Testing");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, 215454);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());
    getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + k.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
    Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(Context.this,
            RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);

    break;
```

What Am I doing wrong?
Is there something that I am missing?
I have all permissions, file is created but doesn't have any sound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you should copy your file to SD-card firstly, then use this copy as ringtone. Here full code sample (I have file "kalimba.mp3" in my assets):

```
private int size;

private static final int BUFFER_LEN = 1024;

private void copyFile(AssetManager assetManager, String fileName, File out) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    size = 0;
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(out);
    InputStream is = assetManager.open(fileName);       
    int read = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_LEN];
     while ((read = is.read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_LEN)) >= 0) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, read);
            size += read;
      }
    fos.flush();    
    fos.close();
    is.close();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {        
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            "/myRingtonFolder/Audio/");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
    }

    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath() + "/myRingtonFolder/Audio/";

    File out = new File(path + "/", "kalimba.mp3");     
    if(!out.exists()){
        try {
            copyFile(assetManager, "kalimba.mp3", out);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }           

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, out.getAbsolutePath());
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "name");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, out.length());
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, R.string.app_name);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, true);

    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(out.getAbsolutePath());
    ContentResolver mCr = getContentResolver();
    Uri newUri = mCr.insert(uri, values);

    try {
        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this,    RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
        Settings.System.putString(mCr, Settings.System.RINGTONE,
                newUri.toString());
    } 
    catch (Throwable t) 
    {
        //TODO Handle exception
    }

}
```

Comment: And how can I do that?

Comment: Add methods for copying to my answer. Hope it will be useful for you

Comment: Awesome! One more question, how do I determine where will my file be saved? So I can get path.

Comment: You could use out.getPath(), or out.getAbsolutePath() if you're need it

Comment: Hey sorry it's me again. I tried with this code you wrote above, but I can't make it work.
Is there any other way? Or could you at least add your part of the code in my code above?

Comment: Yes, I've add full code sample which set custom ringtone. I've check it on my device and its works

Comment: Awesome, will give you bounty in 22 hours. I can't do it atm because of timer.

Comment: One more question, I hope I am not annoying you I am kinda new to android development.
I get this error: BUFFER_LENcannot be resolved to a variable. Which variable should I set for this?
Also at Settings.System.putString(mCr, Settings.System.RINGTONE,

Which settings should I import? There is lots of them

Comment: BUFFER_LEN is a constant, I've add it to my sample. For settings you should use android.provider.Settings package.

Comment: Um so now it creates file in folder, but same thing happens again, file doesn't have any sound and it's size is 00kb
http://prntscr.com/2tw8uy

Comment: Maybe you have old record in settings, which have old path which is incorrect? Try to clear settings, or [update](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#update%28android.net.Uri,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) record in code, and then if update return 0 - insert.